# MSSS Management Studio Object Explorer changes from 2005 to 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm connecting to a database server (MSSS 2005, 9.0 SP2) which is almost totally without my control.

If I connect to it using Management Studio 2005 I can browse the list of tables, views, other objects in some of the databases using object explorer.

If I connect to it using Management Studio 2008, I cannot see the list. I can write queries against them so the objects are there, but I cannot browse them.

Can anyone suggest what permissions I'm lacking or what (default) options are changed in the newer version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permission you are lacking is "view any definition".  Go to the server sercurity settings, double click your login.  Open the "securables" page.  Click "Search" and then select the server.  You should now see the permissions in the lower pane.

Alternatively, you can grant the permission using Sql:

```
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO [YourUserName]
```

You might ask for these rights as well:

- VIEW ANY DATABASE
- VIEW SERVER STATE